# How do I convert cents retained as integers to dollars as decimals?

Tags: datatypes, redshift, number-formatting

I have *cent* values, retained as `integers`, that I need to convert to *dollars* and show them as a `decimals`.

**Example**

A value is kept as `1925`, so I need to be able to return `19.25`.

This is what I had been doing in MySQL

```
format(price/ 100, 2) as amount
```

and when summing the value, I use

```
cast(SUM(price) / 100 AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) as total_amount
```

These seem to work fine, but when moving over to Redshift, I am not sure if I am using the right function.

**Current attemtp**

In Redshift, I try with

```
price :: DECIMAL(12, 2) as amount
```

and then

```
SUM(price)/ 100 :: DECIMAL(12, 2) as total_amount
```

In both instances, I get 4 decimal points in my results? Is using wrapping these functions with `trunc(,2)` a good way to solve this?

Comment: Maybe `ROUND(price :: DECIMAL(12, 2), 2)` or `ROUND(price :: DECIMAL, 2)` or use [TO_CHAR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_CHAR.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ROUND](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ROUND.html) or [TO_CHAR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_CHAR.html)

### Using [ROUND](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ROUND.html)

```sql
ROUND(price :: DECIMAL(12, 2), 2) as amount
-- or
ROUND(price :: DECIMAL, 2) as amount
-- or
ROUND(SUM(price)/ 100 :: DECIMAL(12, 2), 2) as total_amount
-- or
ROUND(SUM(price)/ 100 :: DECIMAL, 2) as total_amount
```

### USING [TO_CHAR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_CHAR.html)

```sql
TO_CHAR(price :: DECIMAL(12, 2), 'FM99999999.99') as amount
-- or
TO_CHAR(price :: DECIMAL, 'FM99999999.99') as amount
-- or
TO_CHAR(SUM(price)/ 100 :: DECIMAL(12, 2), 'FM99999999.99') as total_amount
-- or
TO_CHAR(SUM(price)/ 100 :: DECIMAL, 'FM99999999.99') as total_amount
```

[Format strings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_formating.html) are explained in more detail [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_formating.html).